# i18n file location and format for Named Spaced Form Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, rails-i18n, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a form object

#### app/form_models/car_registration/basics.rb

```
module CarRegistration
  class Basics < Base
     include ActiveModel::Model
     delegate :name, :name=, to: :vehicle
  end
end
```

#### app/views/car_registration/basics.html.erb

```
 <%= simple_form_for( @form_object, url: wizard_path, :method => :put) do |f| %>  
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I could not figure it out by referencing this:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

As I created the below file, but it does not seem to change my form label.

#### config/locales/form_models/car_registration/basics/en.yml

#### en.yml

```
en:
  name: English Name
```

#### simple_form.en.yml

```
en:
  simple_form:
     car_registration/basics:
        label:
          name: english Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form base object is an ActiveModel one, the yaml namespace to override names derived from the objects and attributes would be like this:

```
en:
  activemodel:
    models:
      car_registration/basics:
        one: BasicsSingular
        other: BasicsPlural
    attributes:
      car_registration/basics:
        name: NameAttributeTranslation
```

If they are ActiveRecord objects, replace `activemodel` with `activerecord` in the yaml file.

Comment: It's a form object, using Active Model, and it is using Simple_form. any ideas?

Comment: @user2012677 Yes. The answer above should work for you then, are you having trouble with it?

Comment: why is car_registration/basics: listed twice?, No it does not work.

Comment: @user2012677 The listing under `attributes` is to control the labels for attributes of the `car_registration/basics` "model". The one/other keys under `models` controls how it might display the model name itself. With the form setup as above, by default `<%= f.submit %>` would be labeled as "Create Basics", but because I added singular/plural options under `models`, it would say "Create BasicsSingular". I thought maybe you'd like to know how to override/translate both the name field and the button.

Comment: @user2012677 I made a full reproduction of this in a simple app, and what I said is working for me, but I think I found a way to also make it work with your `simple_form.en.yml`. I think your nested yaml file directory structure isn't being loaded by Rails. Add this to `config/application.rb`: `config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]` to load all sub-directories of `config/locales` as shown in the Rails I18n guide here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#organization-of-locale-files

Comment: Thank you, it work now.  Overwrote my model name and I needed to use that name.  Your help was very helpful!